# What is the name of the Technology that generates research from Surveys?

Tags: stellaris

In Stellaris there is a technology that gives you a small research boost whenever you survey a system. I don't remember what the name is and I've searched through the wiki without luck. Can anyone tell me the name of it (and whether it's Physics/Society/Engineering)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind! It's not a Technology, it's a Tradition: Planetary Survey Corps (Discovery). This explains both why I'd seen it before, and why I couldn't find it in the wiki.

Comment: mark yourself as the answer.